# SSD compatibility Alienware Area-51 R2

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Computer parts are really not my speciality and I am trying to extend my [Alienware Area-51 R2](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/alienware-area51-r2/diagnose) from 2015 with an additional SSD. However I am bit lost with the technical terms and how they fit together. In the specifications of the [Alienware Area-51 R2](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln296972/alienware-area-51-r2-system-specifications?lang=en) I see there is

```
M2
    • One M.2 card slot for WLAN and Bluetooth 
    • Storage Four SATA ports
```

I am thinking about buying an SSD that has this: `Some Vendor XXX (1000GB, M.2 2280)`

I read in a thread about someone complaining that his M.2 SSD wont work with the Alienware Area 51 R2. I am now confused, if this should work or not. Are there requirements regarding the motherboard or some drivers that could mean I have a slot for M.2 2280 SSD but it wont work with any M.2 2280 SSD?

Comment: @harrmyc Its not a hardware recommendation? All I want to know is if it is technically possible to use this SSD with my computer... How on earth will it become quickly obsolete if this device is compatible with my computer?

Comment: @DavidPostill see above

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the info, I also saw this community but assumed its the wrong place as I am not specifically looking for a recommendation, but good to know :). I am using an Alienware Area-51 R2 according to dxdiag.

Comment: I will,  and from what I can see with the R2 I am out of luck, only 2.5" SATA I/II/III apparently.

Comment: Please go to http://dell.com/support/home/us/en/19?app=products&~ck=mn and enter your service tag to confirm that. If so,  the M.2 slot is dedicated to wireless and will not accept an M.2 SATA or NVMe drive module. However, you can get a PCIe bus card https://www.google.com/search?num=100&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&q=PCIe+card+for+M.2+drives which will accept M.2 drives if you have PCIe slots open. Which PCIe card slot? See http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2839021/ssd-pci-adapter-worth.html

Comment: My suggestion is to ask the manufacturer directly if the M.2 slot can be used for storage.  Also, buy from a vendor that allows returns, even if you get a positive answer.